# Why aren't these divs next to each other?

Tags: html, css

I have my page setup like this

```
<div id="form">
 <textarea id="p-details"></textarea>
 <div id="price-holder"><span id="price">$99</span></div>
</div>
```

I have my css setup like this

```
#p-details {
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 2px;
width: 500px;
height: 300px;
display: inline-block;
}

#form {
margin: auto;
width: 708px;
}

#price-holder {
display: inline-block;
width: 200px;
height: 300px;
}

#price {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
```

The problem is I cannot figure out how to get #p-details and #price-holder to be directly side by side inside #form. Some help with this would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Div is a block element. Try the following

```
<div style='display:inline-block'>Some text</div><div style='display:inline-block'>Some text</div>
```

BTW. Span is an inline element. It dosent keep the space around it. See [here](http://quirksmode.org/css/css2/display.html).

Answer (score 0):

"Side by side" is a pretty relative term but if I understood your problem correctly you could use simple floats like this.

```
#p-details {
    float:left;
    display:block;
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
}

#form {
    margin: auto;
    width: 708px;
    overflow:hidden;
}

#price-holder {
    float:left;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
}

#price {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```

In case you wish to preserve your inline-block positioning on both container you can keep your existing block and simply use the following redefinition of `#form` to align them.

```
#form {
    margin: auto;
    width: 708px;
    text-align:left;
}
```

Comment: floats here would be overkill. :)

Comment: "Overkill" is also a relative term.

Comment: inline-block is sufficient in my book. See my answer. But I accept that this would work.

Answer (score 0):

When you make elements inline-block, there will be a 4px margin to the side. Thus, the combined width of the two elements, plus the 4px margins, plus the border on #p-details is greater than 708px. I believe you have not accounted for the additional 4px of width created by the border.

Try changing your stylesheet to this:

```
#p-details, #price-holder {
display: inline-block;
height: 300px;
}

#p-details {
-webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
-moz-box-sizing: border-box;
box-sizing: border-box;
border: 2px solid black;
border-radius: 2px;
width: 500px;
}

#form {
margin: auto;
width: 708px;
}

#price-holder {
width: 200px;
}

#price {
font-weight: bold;
font-size: 20px;
text-align: center;
display: block;
}
```

Comment: The extra margin is not 4 pixels, but 'the width of a single space in the currently active font'. The elements being declared inline makes the whitespace between them, collapsed to a single space, create a small margin.

Comment: Currently, though, it is sufficient to overcome this with a margin of -4px or word-spacing on the parent element set to -4px, no?

Comment: It works for most fonts at common screen sizes, but will break right away when you apply it in a container with a much larger (or smaller) font causing a space to become either 3 or 5 pixels instead of 4. The more durable solutions to the issue use absolute positioning or floats regrettably.

Comment: I agree with you, though I stand by the fact that what is causing the issue in the question above is probably the 4px margins/whitespace (whichever way we look at it) plus the border width. :)

Answer (score 0):

You may try this, [**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/yL2Hn/)

```
#p-details {
    border: 2px solid black;
    border-radius: 2px;
    width: 500px;
    height: 300px;
    display: inline-block;
    float:left;
}

#form {
    margin: auto;
    width: 715px;
}

#price-holder {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 200px;
    height: 300px;
    float:left;
}

#price {
    font-weight: bold;
    font-size: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    display: block;
}
```